# Sub-setting with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, dplyr, percentage

Dataframe has the columns:

**State   Sex  Year  Name Number Percent**

I need to filter for each **year**, one **male** and one **female** with highest **percentage**, in every **state**.

Example:

```
Washington  M   2011   John    34   0.46
Washington  F   2011   Mary    42   0.67


Washington M   2012   John    46   0.46
Washington F   2012   Mary    64   0.67
```

and so on for every State and year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
df %>% 
  group_by(State, Year, Sex) %>% 
  slice(which.max(Percent))
```

Comment: Thx docento. Seems fine